# Aura ltng:require having different behavior in Lightning Pages and Digital Experience(Aura)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, digital-experience, lightning-page

Why the aura ltng:require is having a different behavior in Lightning Pages vs Digital Experience(Aura)?

I am having problem that the afterScriptsLoaded is been executed every time that there is an update into a Record Page in Digital Experience.
In lightning Pages, this behavior doesn't happen. I can update a record and the afterScriptsLoaded is not going to be executed.

Here is a simple aura.
TestComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
  <ltng:require
    scripts="..myscript.js"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"
  />
  
  <h1>Test Component - Auto Refresh</h1>
</aura:component>
```

TestComponentController.js

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded: function (pComponent, pEvent, pHelper) {
        console.log('[afterScriptsLoaded] Starts....');
    },
    reloadComponent: function (pComponent, pEvent, pHelper) {
        console.log('[reloadComponent] Starts....');
    },
})
```

This is the scenario:

1. Go to a Lightning Record Page, and add this component, and save and go to any record page that you have this component. Update a field from the record. You should not see any console.log. I should see only one which was from when I loaded my page.
2. Now go to Digital Experience - Aura Site, then create a record detail page, and add the component there, Preview that as Authenticated User and edit any field. You will see the log being executed every time you update a field and save.

I basically got into this issue because I am using this code below, my component needs to know when it is a load for the first time, and when I need to refresh or an update. The problem is that in Digital Experience, when a field is updated, the RefreshView is executed and is followed by afterScriptsLoaded which says to my component that we just started the component, which overrides the behavior of changed event. In lightning pages everything works fine.

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.reloadComponent}" />
```

Did I miss something for Digital Experience or that is normal?

Thank you in advanced!